# Populate Array of UUIDs using Sequilize

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have the following row in my table

```
{
  column1: <uuid>,
  column2: [
     <uuid>,
     <uuid>,
     <uuid>
  ]
}
```

I can populate `column1` using `include` from sequilize like below

```
TableName.findAll({
  include: [Column1]
})
```

**Now How can I populate `column2` ?**.
As it's an array of `uuid`s I can't user direct `include` in the query, like when I tried below

```
TableName.findAll({
  include: [Column1],
  include: [Column2],
})
```

It's throwing an error 
`SequelizeEagerLoadingError: column2 is not associated to tablename!`

Comment: try this 

    TableName.findAll({
      include: [Column1, column2],
    })

Comment: Yeah tried. Didn't worked. It is considering column2 as `uuid` but it's `Array[uuid]`